# Why am I getting 'cannot find symbol' error?

Tags: java, smack

The following statement shows an error :

```
Presence p_tester = Presence(Presence.Type.available,"having lunch",1,
                                                       Presence.Mode.available);
```

The error higlighted by the IDE is :

```
cannot find symbol
symbol: method Presence(Type,String,int,Mode)
```

Why am I getting this error though I have imported the correct class 
*`(org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence)`*?

Answer (score 3):

Because keyword `new` is missing. Try following:

```
Presence p_tester = new Presence(Presence.Type.available,"having lunch",1,
                                                       Presence.Mode.available);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `new` before calling the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
cannot find symbol
symbol: method Presence(Type,String,int,Mode)
```

BECAUSE you are missing `new` keyword

so try

```
Presence p_tester = new Presence(Presence.Type.available,"having lunch",1,
                                                       Presence.Mode.available);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keyword **`new`** is missing. Try this:-

```
Presence p_tester = new Presence(Presence.Type.available,"having lunch",1,
                                                       Presence.Mode.available);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be the constructor :
Presence(Presence.Type.available,"having lunch",1,
                                                       Presence.Mode.available)
does not exists or is not accessible.

Comment: No. See other answers.